package identifier or launch activity not found
Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file, I checked everything, it seems like no issue to me. Can some please check this?
I read some articles but I found no issue.
Here is some more explanation:
package identifier or launch activity not found.
Please check /Users/armagangok/Development/Flutter/AppSweat/pomodoro_app/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml for errors.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_arm64.
Is your project missing an android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXACT_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />
    
    <application
        android:label="Pomodoro App"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ***package="com.appsweat.pomodoro_app">*** // I added this line and problem resolved

